# x86 how does Linux signal interrupt instruction stream

Tags: linux, x86, operating-system, signals

How does a Linux signal lead to the instruction stream of the X86 processor getting interrupted? So what CPU facility is used?

You have synchronous and asynchronous interrupts.

Synchronous interrupts are for issues like page faults, exceptions etc. Problems that are caused by the instructions that are executing on the CPU.

Asynchronous interrupts are from an IPI from the LAPIC, timer interrupt or for an interrupt picked up by the I/O-APIC and routed to the right LAPIC which then interrupts the processor. So these are external events.

But which X86 mechanism does the Signal use to interrupt the instruction stream and start processing the signal handler.

It isn't an asynchronous interrupt AFAIK because interrupts are handled within the kernel and signals in user-space. But its behavior is very similar to that of an asynchronous interrupt.

Comment: Interesting question.  I wonder why it collected a downvote:(

Answer (score 3):

**The kernel has to deliver a signal to user-space.**  You're right that that doesn't just happen on its own in hardware.  That's why signal handling can respect the user-space red-zone, `sigaltstack`, and default actions if there's no handler registered.

**As soon as the kernel has control, it can deliver the signal to user-space** (or do the default action of ignoring it or killing the process).

If the signal was sent by a process running on another core, to a process running on *this* core, then probably it's delivered to user-space from an IPI handler, or else just at the next timer interrupt or system call that gives the kernel a chance to check for a pending signal.

When the IPI interrupt handler is preparing to return to user-space, it notices that there's a pending interrupt for the process that it's about to return to.  (Either with a special case for one type of IPI, or by running the scheduler since we're in the kernel anyway).  **Instead of using `iret` to return to the interrupt frame pushed by hardware for the async interrupt, the kernel instead can `iret` to the address of the user-space signal handler.**

The whole point of using an IPI (if that's what Linux even does) is to transfer control to the kernel sooner, instead of just waiting for it to notice the pending signal the next time it calls `schedule()`.

---

If the process the signal is sent to isn't currently running on any core, then it either wakes the process up if there's a free CPU, or the signal just sits there for that task until the scheduler on some core decides to run it on this core.  At that point it will notice and deliver the pending signal.

Comment: Making the process aware that an event occurred isn't the problem. My question is what triggers instruction stream to be interrupted so that the signal handler code can execute.

Comment: @pveentjer: you already described IPIs in the question.  An IPI that arrives while the kernel is executing in CPL=3 will transfer control to the kernel at its IPI-handler entry point, like any other interrupt.  Once the kernel has control, obviously it can do whatever it wants, including `iret` to user-space at the user-space signal-handler address.

Comment: But an interrupt always gets processed in kernel space. Signals in user space. Something doesn't compute (probably my understanding).

Comment: @pveentjer: I already edited my last comment, see the last sentence.

Comment: Ok. So that is the trick. It starts as a interrupt in kernel space and then it switches to user space to processing the signal handler. I thought this was prevented with signals. That is why I couldn't place it.